# ag-grid enterprise performance display upgrade

Tags: ag-grid

Are there any ag-grid performance display upgrades from free to the enterprise version? As in, if I upgrade to ag-grid enterprise, will I have the ability to view more rows of data with less lag when scrolling compared to the free version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of rendering is not changed by upgrading to ag-grid **enterprise** version.

In the enterprise version, you can control how much data you want to bring to the UI. For example, if it is grouped by a few columns, your backend handler can bring only what a user can see in the grid. There is a lot of control over how we bring data to the UI.

Enterprise provides rich features like Pivoting, Aggregation, Clipboard, Column Menu,Context Menu, Exporting to Excel, Grouping of rows, Master Details pattern, Tree design, tool panel and so on. [See more here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-features/) and look for features with **Ⓔ**.

On the other hand if you are looking to improve performance on UI, then you can consider the following:

- Avoid custom cell renderers unless it is critical. And even you need one, go for plain JS instead of frameworks
- Increase `rowBuffer` (by default it's 20)
- Avoid using animations.
- Use `batchUpdateRowData()` which executes updates in batch after 50ms unlike `updateRowData()` which is executed immediately. [Read more](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-performance/)

Note: Delay in execution is driven by property `batchUpdateWaitMillis`.

Comment: Update: Grid API updateRowData() deprecated, replaced with applyTransaction() Grid API batchUpdateRowData() deprecated, replaced with applyTransactionAsync() Grid Property batchUpdateWaitMillis deprecated, replaced with asyncTransactionWaitMillis. [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update/)